# How to get "child" rows directly in any to many relationship EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have EF6 model with many to many relationship like this (I simplified my model to make it more clear):

```
 public class Card 
 {
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string CardTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CardLayout> CardLayouts { get; set; }
 }

 public class Layout
 {
    public int LayoutId { get; set; }
    public string LayoutTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CardLayout> CardLayouts { get; set; }
 }

 public class CardLayout // relationship table
 {
    public int CardLayoutId { get; set; }
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public int LayoutId { get; set; }

    public int CardLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
    public virtual Layout Layout { get; set; }
 }
```

This is how I use it for now:

```
 int exampleId = 23;
 using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
 {
     Card c = ctx.Cards.Find(23);

     foreach (CardLayout cardLayout in c.CardLayouts)
     {
          Layout layout = cardLayout.Layout;
          DoSomethingWithLayout(layout);
     }
 }
```

**I need Layout collection directly inside my Card object. I don't want to pass thru relationship table. I want to use it like this:**

```
 int exampleId = 23;
 using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
 {
     Card c = ctx.Cards.Find(23);

     foreach (Layout layout in c.Layouts)
     {
          DoSomethingWithLayout(layout);
     }
 }
```

I have tried something like this:

```
public class Card 
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string CardTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CardLayout> CardLayouts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Layout> Layouts { get; set; }
 }
```

But `Layouts` collection is always empty.

**My question is: how can I access Layouts collection directly from Card object? I want to keep Card.CardLayouts collection too, because my CardLayouts table contains fields (like CardLocation in my simplified example)**

Ps. Can someone improve my question title? My english is not good enough to write it better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to introduce a business layer to provide isolation between domain objects/models and entities from your database. Using LINQ, you should then be able to project into an `IQueryable<CardModel>` that collapses complex relationships the way you want to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think that @Biscuits' comment is correct. If you don't want to go that route for whatever reason, you should just be able to create another property with a getter only.

```
 public class Card 
 {
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string CardTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CardLayout> CardLayouts { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Layout> Layouts
    {
       get
       {
         return this.CardLayouts.Select(cl => cl.Layout);
       }
    }
 }
```